# Xerox WorkCentre 3225 not saving scans after several scans made

Tags: printer, scanner

I bought last year a brand new WorkCentre 3225 mainly to scan postcards. (front/back) manually. I have noticed that after several scans 10-15, at the time that I pressed the button No on the screen meaning that I don't want to do other scans, the files were not saved on my pc. I also couldn't connect to the user again because I got `Not available`. I tried to rename the user, disable/enable it without luck. The only sollution that it worked was to reinstall the printer again.

So basically there isn't a fixed number of scans set and if I do more it will crash. I will never know when to stop in orders the files to get saved on my pc. Recently the scans that I can do is lower. Basically I can do 1 or 2 scans and if I do more it will crash again. So the process is, make 1 scan, type that I don't want to scan anything else, the file is saved on my pc and after that I start the process again of scanning. If I do 3-4 scans I have to reinstall my printer because the user gets blocked.

This is very frustrating because I had this issue from the beginning, it doesn't seem to be a issue only with this printer, I tend to think that all of the printers same model has this issue and nobody did that much scans to find out about this. Probably most of the peoples use this for printing mainly and don't do many scans.

My question is, what options do I have? Anybody had this issue? Found a fix? What I can say for sure is that I won't buy any other Xerox Workcentre item anymore in this life.

Comment: This is a technical support request, and is probably better suited for superuser.com.